# How to change the selected item style?

Tags: react-native, dropdown, selecteditem

I use MaterialDropdown from "react-native-material-dropdown", it's working fine but I'd like to change the style of the selected item to make it more visible.
I used selectedItemColor to make it black but I'd like to make it bold and underlined... I don't know how  `"selectedItemStyle"` doesn't work:

```
             <MaterialDropdown
                data={data_dropdown}
                // pickerStyle={styles.dropdownPickerStyle}
                affixTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
                itemTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
                selectedItemStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', textDecorationLine: 'underline'}}
                selectedItemColor='rgb(0, 0, 0)'
                containerStyle={[styles.dropdownContainerStyle, {opacity: 0}]}
                itemCount={10}
                dropdownPosition={-4.5}
                dropdownOffset={{top: 32, left: 5 }}
                underlineColor='transparent'
                labelExtractor={({ label }) => label}
                valueExtractor={({ value }) => value}
                //propsExtractor={({ props }, index) => props}
                propsExtractor={({value, index}) => { return (value === '*' ? {style: 
                               {borderBottomColor: '#D1D1D1', borderBottomWidth: 1, paddingTop: 5}} : 
                               {style: {}}) }}
                onChangeText={(value) => this.choiceAction(value)}
                useNativeDriver={true}
              />
```

Comment: Based on the code, its not possible https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/blob/master/src/components/dropdown/index.js as there are only two files you can copy them to your source and update as required

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the [source-code](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/blob/master/src/components/dropdown/index.js), selectedItemStyle isn't supported as a prop in react-native-material-dropdown. You have to make a pull request.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I asked the question in github, hum, I don't really know how to make pull request...